# Are there stats for a fast, maneuverable animal-drawn vehicle for one person?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, vehicles

The existing vehicles in the PHB, like carts and wagons, are made for slow, overland movement and transport. Both are heavy and not easy to maneuver in.

Does D&D 3.5e have an animal-drawn vehicle a single PC to ride in that is maneuverable and fast? Preferably pulled by one creature, and not limited to just one environment (e.g., a dogsled can only work in a cold environment).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50620/discussion-between-simon-and-sevensideddie).

Comment: This still isn't quite clear enough to be a good question.  What's it for?  Why not just ride a horse, what is it you want out of the vehicle itself, you don't say?  Fast overland or on the battle map?  Fast meaning faster than a man, or faster than a horse, or just faster than a cart?  Is it for combat or just transport? If the obvious answers of e.g. "chariot" aren't good, explain the attributes you're looking for that makes it not.

Comment: I'm not going to rework them more. I've just arrived back and upon seeing this I am happy with the answer given. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Arms and Equipment Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/078692649X) (D&D 3.0) there are the rules to create vehicles and some example. The more maneuverable is the cart (average).

Answer (score 1):

### For D&D 3.5, only for Sleds

The player handbook give us a price, weight and description for [Sleds](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm), but no stats are given. Nor does it have any reference for sleighs.

> **Sled**
>
> Price: 20 gp  Weight: 300 lb.
>
> This is a wagon on runners for moving through snow and over ice. In general, two horses (or other beasts of burden) draw it. A sled comes with the harness needed to pull it.

However, pathfinder (which is 3.5e compatible), does have price, weight and stats for [Dog Sleds](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/vehicles/land-vehicles/dog-sled):

> DOG SLED
>
> Price 20 gp; Passage 3 CP
>
> This sled is designed to be pulled over snow and ice by a team of trained riding dogs. Most sleds have runners at the back for a musher to stand on. A dog sled can carry up to the capacity of all the dogs that pull it.

And also for [Sleighs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/vehicles/land-vehicles/sleigh) (which has full statistics on the vehicle):

> SLEIGH
>
> Price 50 gp; Passage 2 CP
>
> This wagon has runners, making it an ideal conveyance for snow and ice travel. In general, two horses (or other beasts of burden) are needed to draw it. A sled comes with the harness required to pull it.

As for the stats of the riding dogs, they can be found [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/dog/riding-dog), while horses can be found [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/horse.htm).

Answer (score 1):

A flying carpet.

The only "problem" with that solution, is finding a creature able and willing to pull it. On the plus side, you can use the carpet to find and catch the creature in mind.

NB: The smaller the carpet, the better its maneuverability.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be an answer for this question as what you are describing is the role of a horse and saddle. There won't be a horse drawn vehicle to replace this as there wouldn't be an advantage to such a vehicle. The closest thing is probably the chariot, which there are [homebrew rules](https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Chariot_(3.5e_Variant_Rule)) for and are typically, historically, for 2 people.

Thanks to [Hey I Can Chan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/8610/hey-i-can-chan) for pointing out there are official, 3rd edition rules for chariots in *[Sword and Fist](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786918292)* on pages 78-9.

The only alternative I can think of would be using something like *[Tenser's Floating Disk](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/floatingDisk.htm)* and following along behind another player. However, this would only be as maneuverable as the player it's following and only as fast as their normal movement, so you're looking at 20-30ft movement unless your wizard is playing a non-standard race or took a barbarian dip or something.